# Run only last python function call within some timeframe?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, coroutine

Let's say I have a function that updates some internal states of the application:

```
def on_change(*args, **kwargs):
    pass  # some compute intensive state change
```

This function can run up to hundred times a second (due to many mousewheel events triggering the update) - I would only like to execute the above function once and only the last call should be executed.

What is the best design pattern for managing such a situation? The only way I can think of is spawning a separate thread for each on_change call and share a variable between them, but this sounds overly messy...

Thanks!

Comment: Read up on [`class threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=timer#threading.Timer) and `cancel()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Waiter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.args = ()
        self.kwargs = {}
        self.changed = False

    def on_change(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This is the event handler
        # It does nothing but save the latest arguments
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.changed = True

    def tick(self):
        # Call this function once per second, or whatever
        if self.changed:
            # Do your updates, using self.args and self.kwargs
            self.changed = False
```

Since you mentioned mouse events you are evidently writing a GUI application.  All GUI engines, in my experience, have timers and the ability to call functions on a periodic basis.  Use that capability to call tick periodically.